# KNIME: Compare if One Column Contains a subset of another column

Tags: java, string, comparison, knime

In Knime I am trying to compare if a value in one column is contained within another column. I tried to do this using "LIKE" in the Rule Engine but couldn't get the wildcards to work with a column input instead of a string. E.g.

```
For row1 I want to check if column 1, row 1 is within column 2, row 1
For row2 I want to check if column 1, row 2 is within column 2, row 2
```

Like is "ABC" contained within "test ABCtest"

Does the "LIKE" in Rule Engine only allow hard coded strings for comparison? Other ideas to achieve this? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [String Manipulation](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.base.node.preproc.stringmanipulation.StringManipulationNodeFactory) node with the `regexMatcher` can help here, though the result will be String (with values `True`/`False` by default), so further node will be required if for example a number is required (if different String, you can use the `?`/`:` ternary operator like `== "True" ? "when true" : join("when false it was because '", $columnReference$, "' was not found")`).

You can use `regexMatcher` like this ([`\Q`/`\E`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quot) helps to avoid treating the content in `Reference` column as a regular expression (except when it contains `\E`)):

```
regexMatcher($text$, join(".*?\\Q", $Reference$, "\\E.*+")) == "True" ? "vrai" : "faux"
```

[image: regexMatcher($text$, join(".*?\Q", $Reference$, "\E.*+"))]

Answer (score 0):

Rule engine allows wildcards with LIKE operator but it does not allow wildcards combined with columns meaning the following will work fine:

```
$column1$ LIKE "*test*" => "1"
```

The following is allowed as well but will not work fine:

```
$column1$ LIKE "*$column2$*" => "1"
```

The reason is when you got double quotes $ is not recognized so you do not get the values from column2. Instead you get same string each time: `"*$column2$*"` which is not what you want.

Additionally you can use `indexOf()` function in String Manipulation or Column Expressions node that will return the first position of string value from column1 in column2. If not found the function will return -1. Follow it with Rule Engine node to add appropriate indication.